# Setting which Text view to use to open Url

Tags: ios, url, swift, textview

Hello am making an app where the user presses an butten and a random link opens! But i have problems with making the textview were the user presses to recognize that it is a Url to open

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate,   
NSObjectProtocol {



@IBOutlet weak var randomButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var firsttext: UITextView!

let links = 
["http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com",
"http://www.discovery.com"]
var currentLinkIndex : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firsttext.delegate = self
}


func textview(textview: UITextView!, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL,
inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

    let url = NSURL(string:links[currentLinkIndex])
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
    return false
}

@IBAction func randomButtonaction(sender: UIButton) {

    let random : Int = Int(arc4random()) % 3 
    firsttext.text = links[random]
    currentLinkIndex = random
}

}
```

Do i have to inside "func textview...ShouldinteractWithUrl..." name that i want the firsttext to be the one thats should be enable to interact with url and then open? How do i set it to do so?